# Python converting text date

Tags: python, date

I'm **scraping** some data and I got this format of date: February 23rd and would like to change it to 2021-02-23 using Python.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is how you use [strftime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50256825/datetime-strftime-and-strptime) you can learn more about what each tags mean by `man strftime` if on unix based system

Comment: @mTvare `strftime` would work in most cases, but it doesn't play very nice when dealing with strings that have `th`, `st`, or `rd`. Also, since the string is missing the year value, `strftime` would default to `1900`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) module for parsing strings into dates that have non-standard formats that otherwise `strftime` could handle

```
from dateutil.parser import parse    

print(parse('February 23rd'))

>>> 2021-02-23 00:00:00
```

Since the year is missing from the input, `parse` defaults to current year